Is torque and change in angular momentum always in the same direction?

Consider the given image. If a torque parallel to z-axis is applied on P, the angular velocity of P (and hence the linear velocity) changes.
Now, the angular momentum of P perpendicular to z-axis (parallel to radius vector CP) is given by
L = OC * mv. ---- (i)
Since velocity of P changes due to the applied torque, L should also change (from (i)).
Thus, torque applied parallel to z-axis (perpendicular to CP) changes angular momentum perpendicular to z-axis which doesn't seem correct vectorially.
Please correct me.

Vectorially, $\tau$ is defined to be $\frac{\text{d}L}{\text{t}}$. If you’re asking the question in the title, the answer is unequivocally yes, barring anything like relativity.

a) Is this for a particle or a rigid body. b) Is the particle accelerate in the tangential direction and/or does angular velocity vary?

@controlgroup - actually you need to be careful if the reference frame origin (point of summation for angular momentum and torque) is moving or not. If it is moving then $$ {\bf \tau} = \frac{{\rm d}{\bf L}}{{\rm d}t} + {\bf v}_A \times {\bf p}$$ where ${\bf v}_A$ is the velocity vector of the reference point and ${\bf p}$ linear momentum.

Good point. Without one explicitly given I took the origin to just be where that simplified a bit.

No, it is not always the case for Classical Mechanics. To define torque and angular momentum you need a point of reference about which you do the summation of quantities, and if this point is moving with constant speed (still an inertial frame) then the relationship is
$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_A = \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \boldsymbol{L}_A + \boldsymbol{v}_A \times \boldsymbol{p}  $$
where



quantity
description




$\boldsymbol{\tau}_A$
equipollent torque acting on the body (instanteneously) summed on the reference point A.


$\boldsymbol{L}_A$
rotational momentum of rigid body summed on the reference point A.


$\boldsymbol{p}$
translational momentum of the rigid body.


$\boldsymbol{v}_A$
instanteneous velocity of reference point A.



The cases where $\boldsymbol{v}_A \times \boldsymbol{p} = 0$ and torque and angular momentum are parallel are

Reference point A is fixed.
Body is purely rotating and thus has no momentum
Reference point A is co-moving parallel to body momentum (velocity of center of mass)
Reference is center of mass.

There for the common case where the equations of rotational motion are expressed at the center of mass (point C) the above is
$$ \require{cancel} \boldsymbol{\tau}_C = \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \boldsymbol{L}_C + \cancel{ \boldsymbol{v}_C \times \boldsymbol{p}}  $$
which is the equation most commonly found in dynamics textbooks.


See section 3.2.2, equation 3.80 Dynamics
(Mechanics III), Institute of Mechanical Systems
Department of Mechanical and Process Engineering
ETH Zurich



and a practical example where this is important






See also my simple derivation at https://ja72.github.io/Rigid%20Body%20Dynamics.html equation (15) and subsequent example for a hanging rod.

The phrasing of the question is really muddled, idk, I am going to start with Newton to refresh my memory and then go to the angular version.
So the Newton analog is "force", ${\vec F}$, and change in momentum , ${\vec p}$ always in the same direction?
We know:
$$ \vec F = m\vec a $$
A classic equation.
Actually, let's use Einstein summation notation:
$$ F_i = m a_i $$
Now what? $m$ is scalar, so answering "yes" sounds good, but how do we show that?
I think we want to calculate the vector rejection of $\vec F$ on $\vec a$. The rejection is:
$$ {\rm rej}_F(\vec a) = 
\vec a - {\rm proj}_F(\vec a)
$$
where the vector projection is
$$ {\rm proj}_F(\vec a) = [(\vec a \cdot \hat F)\hat F]_i
= \frac{a_jF_j}{F_jF_j}F_i $$
Ok. Now what?
$$ {\rm rej_F}(a_i) = a_i  - \frac{a_jF_j}{F_jF_j}F_i 
$$
to which I can apply Newton's Law:
$$ {\rm rej_F}(a_i) = a_i  - \frac{m(a_ja_j)}{(ma_jma_j)}ma_i 
$$
$$ {\rm rej_F}(a_i) = a_i  - \frac{(a_ja_j)}{m(a_ja_j)}ma_i 
$$
$$ {\rm rej_F}(a_i) = a_i  - \frac{(a_ja_j)}{(a_ja_j)}a_i 
$$
$$ {\rm rej_F}(a_i) = a_i  - a_i = 0  
$$
So they are indeed parallel (there is zero rejection).
Now we need to upgrade with the torque version:
$$ {\tau}_i = I_{ij}{\alpha}_j $$
where:
$${\alpha}_i = \frac{d\omega_i}{dt} $$
is the angular acceleration, and $I_{ij}$ is the inertia tensor.
So the fact that we have replaced a scalar $m$ with a symmetric rank 2 tensor $I_{ij}$ is significant.
Let see what happens. I am just going to take the above series of calculations with:
$$ F_i \rightarrow {\tau}_i $$
$$ a_i \rightarrow {\alpha}_i $$
$$ m \rightarrow I_{ij} $$
so start with
$$ {\rm rej_{\tau}}(\alpha_i) = \alpha_i  -
\frac{\alpha_j\tau_j}{\tau_k\tau_k}\tau_i 
$$
which with the angular analog of Newton's Law is:
$$ {\rm rej_{\tau}}(\alpha_i) =
\alpha_i  -
\frac{\alpha_jI_{jk}\alpha_k}
{I_{lm}\alpha_mI_{ln}\alpha_n}
I_{ip}\alpha_p 
$$
which is zero if:
$$\alpha_i  =
\frac{\alpha_jI_{jk}\alpha_k}
{I_{lm}\alpha_mI_{ln}\alpha_n}
I_{ip}\alpha_p 
$$
which means:
$$\frac{\alpha_jI_{jk}\alpha_k}
{I_{lm}\alpha_mI_{ln}\alpha_n}
= \delta_{ip}
$$
which is obtuse. If I set:
$$ {\bf n} = {\bf\hat{\alpha}} $$
it basically asks if:
$$ {\bf n}\cdot{\bf I}\cdot{\bf n} = \big({\bf I}\cdot{\bf n}
\big)^2 $$
which is not generally true. So: no.

Just FYI, when I see something like:
$$ \frac{a_j b_j}{c_j d_j}$$
I am inclined to interpret that as:
$$ \frac{a_1 b_1}{c_1 d_1} + \frac{a_2 b_2}{c_2 d_2} + \dots$$
which I don't think is what you wanted.

The last equation cannot be right as $${\bf n}\cdot{\bf I}\cdot{\bf n} \neq \big({\bf I}\cdot{\bf n} \big) \cdot \big({\bf I}\cdot{\bf n} \big) = \big({\bf I}\cdot{\bf n} \big)^2$$

@Amit naw, it's PEDMAS for Einstein.

@JohnAlexiou yes, that is the point of the answer. It's only true if $I_{ij} = m \bar r^2 \delta_{ij}$, that is: equivalent to a scalar (like mass). I prefer to work in spherical tensors, where the 6 DoF of ${\bf I}$ are made from things that look like $Y_0^0(\theta,\phi), Y_2^0(\theta,\phi), Y_2^{\pm 1}(\theta,\phi), Y_0^2(\theta,\phi)$ and the $m=\pm 1$ can be diagonalized away, the real part of $m=\pm 2$ is an azimuthal asymmetry, and $l,m=2,0$ is oblate/prolate depending on sign. If there is only $Y_0^0$, the we have spherical symmetry, and the two (axial)vectors are parallel.
